# How to send the email via MimeKit

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I have service, which send an user information after his some action. It works throught the rabbitmq.
Firstly i had this service as an web api(was working as post method), then moved it to console => after triggering the action => service have to run. But, unfortuanlly, now it doesn't work.

```
public class MailService : IMailService
    {
        private readonly IOptions<MailSettings> _mailSettings;

        public MailService(IOptions<MailSettings> mailSettings)
        {
            _mailSettings = mailSettings;
        }

        public async Task SendMessageAsync(Mail mail)
        {
            var email = new MimeMessage();
            email.Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse(_mailSettings.Value.Mail);
            email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(mail.Email));
            email.Subject = mail.Subject;

            var builder = new BodyBuilder();
            builder.HtmlBody = mail.Body;
            email.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Connect(_mailSettings.Value.Host, _mailSettings.Value.Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            smtp.Authenticate(_mailSettings.Value.Mail, _mailSettings.Value.Password);

            await smtp.SendAsync(email);
            smtp.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
```

And in the console(Program):

```
    IOptions<MailSettings> _mailSettings = Options.Create(new MailSettings
    {
        Mail = "asd.asd@gmail.com",
        DisplayName = "asdasdasd",
        Password = "3frett2get44ewv",
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587
    });
    MailService mailService = new MailService(_mailSettings);

    mailService.SendMessageAsync(new Mail()).GetAwaiter();
```

Comment: Docs for [GetAwaiter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter) say _This method is intended for compiler use rather than for use in application code._ - why are you using that? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Also, SendMessageAsync is trying to set values from the Mail object passed - but you seem to be passing an empty object - `new Mail()`

Comment: @stuartd forgot to mention, in model i've hardcoded and gave default values for props.
i'm using GetAwaiter() cause the fucntion SendMessageAsync returns Task. If i put asynt to static Main, it will not work :) or just to use without GetAwaiter

Comment: The TaskAwaiter returned by that method _supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code._. Why not just use [Wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: @stuartd, woow. thx. so, here it is, sorry i couldn't understand even didnt understand your hint is about to change getawaiter to another method... thank u!